# Creating new df with count of variable from other df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a simple dataframe with one column, 'full dates'.

[image: enter code here]

I would like to create a new data frame with each day in one column and then create another column called 'count' that records how many times that day was entered into my old data frame. So this data snippet would transform into:

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Could you share the dataframes in a format where I don't have to type them in by hand?

Comment: Please share a version of your dummy data for two dataframes and your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -

```
df['full dates'].value_counts()
```

For your use case (if it is this simple), you can treat each date as a categorical variable.

This will produce an output in sorted order (descending) by highest count. Use `sort=False` parameter to maintain original order

In case you are looking for a more foolproof `date` based solution, first parse your column with `pd.to_datetime()` -

```
df['full dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['full dates'], format='%m/%d/%y')
```

Then use [`pd.Grouper()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) to groupby date to get daily count of dates -

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='full dates', freq='D')).count()
```

Comment: Thanks, I am getting this error 'NameError: name 'Grouper' is not defined' with the last grouper line...

Comment: @GrahamStreich you need to use `pd.Grouper` pls check updated ans

Comment: @GrahamStreich does `value_counts()` not work for you?

Comment: Do you know how to sort the 'full dates' variable so it is ordered by time? Thanks

Comment: After casting to date using `pd.to_datetime`, use `df = df.sort_values(by=['fill dates'], ascending=True)`

Comment: I get an error trying to run this line 'df['full dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['full dates'], format='%m/%d/%y')' after running 'df['full dates'].value_counts()''

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this worked:

```
df = dates_cleaned.sort_values(by=['full dates'], ascending=True)

df = pd.DataFrame(df['full dates'].value_counts().reset_index())

df = df.sort_values(by=['index'], ascending=True)

df = df.rename(columns={'index': 'full dates', 'full dates': 'count'})
```